# How to add classes folder in web-inf in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am new to struts. So in eclipse I don't have web-inf->classes, where I should put my struts.xml.In other project I have done this by

> project->properties->java build path->output folder->browse(webcontent->web-inf->classes)->create folder(classes)->advanced->apply.

But now it is not working .the struts.xml file is now created in  java resources->libraries->web app libraries.

Please see the image:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While deploying struts project struts.xml need to bee kept in web inf folder not in classes folder that is in web app folder .Once you copied your struts.xml file in web inf folder refresh your project by right click on project.
Else you can create a new dynamic web project and copy all your files[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[image]

Comment: Hi Gaurav, I am creating the struts.xml file inside web-inf->classes ->struts.xml only.but it is not creating there instead it is getting created inside webapp libraries.I don't know why it is getting created there.Help me to get this done.

Comment: right click on your project and click refresh ..it  is working fine on my side..let me know if you are facing any problems!!!

Comment: it is still getting created inside webapp librariries->webcontent-web-inf

Comment: your project structure should be like as  shown above ..create a new dynamic web project

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse offers the Navigator view which will display your project in the way you are asking. To open this view select Window > Show View > Navigator. then you can see where is your struts.xml if path is not correct check it.